Error Building Android Kernel for Pixel 7 Using Bazel: Missing BUILD File
I am trying to build the Android kernel for the Pixel 7 using Bazel, following the official documentation here. However, I encounter the following error during the build process:
pixel_kernel$ tools/bazel run --config=fast --config=stamp //private/google-modules/soc/gs:panther_dist

ERROR: Skipping '//private/google-modules/soc/gs:panther_dist': no such package 'private/google-modules/soc/gs': BUILD file not found in any of the following directories. Add a BUILD file to a directory to mark it as a package.

 /xxx/pixel_kernel/private/google-modules/soc/gs
WARNING: Target pattern parsing failed.
ERROR: no such package 'private/google-modules/soc/gs': BUILD file not found in any of the following directories. Add a BUILD file to a directory to mark it as a package.

/xxx/pixel_kernel/private/google-modules/soc/gs
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.039s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successful

Steps I followed:refferred this official  page (https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build/building-pixel-kernels),to build kernel but the build failed.

Downloaded kernel source (android-gs-pantah-5.10-android14) using:

repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/manifest -b android-gs-pantah-5.10-android14

repo sync

2. Attempted to build using Bazel since build_panther.sh was not found:
tools/bazel run --lto=thin //gs/google-modules/soc-modules:slider_dist

Expected Outcome: I expect the build to complete successfully and generate the necessary images for flashing the kernel.
Questions:

How can I resolve the 'no such package' error when running tools/bazel run --config=fast --config=stamp //private/google-modules/soc/gs:panther_dist?

Should build_panther.sh be present in the build root directory for this build process, or is using tools/bazel alone sufficient?
Any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated!


